# Polymer observeNodes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, mutation-observers

I an trying a simple test about `observeNodes` Polymer facility. Essentially my code defines an observer for child node changes on the component.

```
<dom-module id="wc-A">
   <template>
      <div>Added Nodes   : <span id="added"></span></div>
      <div>Removed Nodes : <span id="removed"></span></div>
   </template>
   <script>  
      Polymer ({
         is: 'wc-A',
         ready: function () {
            Polymer
               .dom (this)
               .observeNodes (function (nodes) {
                   console.log (nodes) 
                   this.$.added.textContent = nodes.addedNodes.length;
                   this.$.removed.textContent = nodes.removedNodes.length;
               }); 
         }    
      });
   </script>
</dom-module>
```

This example works properly on creation time (from my test `span#added` contains 5 and `span#removed` contains 0), but when I programmatically add/remove elements on the light DOM, the observation mechanism does not respond (`span`'s do not change). This  is my test:

```
<div>
   <button id="btnAdd">New</button>
   <button id="btnRemove">Remove</button>
</div>

<wc-A> <!-- (1) Fires observer -->
  <div class="data">1</div>
  <div class="data">2</div>
</wc-A>

<template id=template>
   <div class="data">3</div>
</template>

<script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady (function () {
       document
          .querySelector ('#btnAdd')
          .addEventListener ('click', function (e) {
              var template = document.querySelector ('#template').content;
              var div = template.querySelector ('div');
              var wcA = document.querySelector ('wc-A')
              wcA.appendChild (div.cloneNode (true)); // (2) Does not fire observer
          });

       document
          .querySelector ('#btnRemove')
          .addEventListener ('click', function (e) {
          var wcA   = document.querySelector ('wc-A')
          var child = wcA.querySelector ('.data');
          if (child)
             wcA.removeChild ( // (3) Does not fire observer
                child
             );
          });
   });
</script>
```

The complete code can be checked http://plnkr.co/edit/DHiH40T3pBLx9Nu6Tv3W?p=preview

What is my error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guess you have this page open already: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#observe-nodes

I tried to do some quick changes to your plunker, adding a `content` tag, but that didn't help either, did see the divs added though with that change.

Seems a bit similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286381/observenodes-for-distributed-content

That said, I have observenodes working for me in an element, but there I don't add childs programatically, but instead rely on `dom-if`, maybe there something with how they are added? #askpolymer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Polymer.dom(this).appendChild` instead of `this.appendChild` to make it work with Polymer 1.0 according to this:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3102